# Тестирование парсинга с большим количеством данных

Tags: тестирование, веб-скрейпинг

Пишу парсер html страниц. Данные будут переноситься в базу данных, каждая запись которой будет формироваться из 5 видов страниц. Всего записей будет примерно 400 за 1 раз. То есть, за 1 раз будет парситься 5 * 400 = 2000 страниц. В одной записи - около 50 полей. Получается, что за 1 раз будет считываться в базу 400 * 50 = 20000 значений

Хочется работу парсера протестировать автоматически, но непонятно, как проверять такое большое количество данных.

Пока видится только один вариант: вручную занести в другую, тестовую БД данные из выборочно взятых, скажем, 5 * 10 = 50 страниц (что будет соответствовать 10 записям в БД), спарсить эти 50 страниц и программно сравнить результат с данными тестовой БД. Или есть еще какие-то способы?

Comment: что именно вы хотите протестировать? какой это будет тест? юнит? интеграционный? функциональный?

Comment: В тестировании, к сожалению, не очень разбираюсь, поэтому не знаю, какие тут нужны тесты. Просто хотелось бы уверенности в том, что данные переносятся в БД без искажений. С парсером буду работать только я, из командной строки, поэтому тестирование интерфейса точно не нужно.

Comment: где вы подозреваете может возникнуть искажение данных?

Comment: Больше всего опасаюсь изменений в структуре кода исходных html файлов, так как: 1) владельцы сайта когда-то могут решить его переделать; 2) из-за такого большого количества html страниц возрастает вероятность того, что даже сейчас код каких-то из них может отличаться от кода большинства остальных.

Comment: вы хотите тестировать не ваш код, а входные данные?

Comment: Я хочу тестировать правильность работы программы. Под правильностью ее работы понимаю перенесение данных сайта в базу данных без искажений.

Comment: вы хотите тестировать как ваш код реагирует на данные - правильные и не правильные? или вы сомневаетесь в правильности вашего кода? или вы сомневаетесь в производительности вашего кода?

Comment: Видимо, первое: хочу тестировать **как код реагирует на данные** - правильные и неправильные.  _Но при этом даже не могу предугадать, какие неправильные данные могут придти, так как неизвестно, как создатели сайта даже сейчас могут разнообразить структуру страниц: или у них все страницы формируются строго однообразно, или будут встречаться страницы с различиями в структуре. Даже если эти различия будут небольшими - из-за них  в процессе переноса в БД данные могут искажаться._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Больше всего опасаюсь изменений в структуре кода исходных html файлов

Если разговор о функциональной составляющей:

1. На первом этапе - тестировать автоматически не получится. В идеале, парсить несколько страниц с целевых ресурсов и проверить "в ручную" что сохранилось в БД и устраивает ли Вас результат.
2. На втором этапе, определить, какова должна быть реакция в случае, если данные которые пришли не соответствуют ожиданиям (например: стопаем парсинг - логгируем - оповещаем или "кривые" данные пишем в другую таблицу - логгируем - оповещаем - переходим к парсингу следующей записи)?
3. На третьем этапе - сгенерировать страницы по структуре повторяющие целевые сайты, но информация на которых заведомо "кривая" (вместо букв - цифры, вместо даты - буквы и т.д.) и попробовать спарсить их. Далее, возвращаемся к шагу 2. Выполняются ли условия, которые мы определили?

> ...не могу предугадать, какие неправильные данные могут придти, так как
>   неизвестно, как создатели сайта даже сейчас могут разнообразить
>   структуру страниц...

С этим в принципе ничего не поделаешь, кроме как договориться с создателями ресурса (покупать у них нужные данные, например).